# What is the square root of the NOT gate?

Tags: quantum-gate, matrix-representation

I have encountered different matrix of operator "the Square Root of NOT gate".

For example, [the matrix is specified here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate):
$\sqrt {NOT}  = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{1 + i}&{1 - i}\\
{1 - i}&{1 + i}
\end{array}} \right)$

And [here a completely different matrix](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100658/rotation-about-the-z-axis-on-the-bloch-sphere) is given:
$\sqrt {NOT}  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&{ - i}\\
{ - i}&1
\end{array}} \right)$

Applying them to the vector $\left| 0 \right\rangle  = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\
0
\end{array}} \right)$, we get different results:

$\sqrt {NOT} \left| 0 \right\rangle  = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{1 + i}&{1 - i}\\
{1 - i}&{1 + i}
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\
0
\end{array}} \right) = \frac{1}{2}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{1 + i}\\
{1 - i}
\end{array}} \right)$

$\sqrt {NOT} \left| 0 \right\rangle  = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1&{ - i}\\
{ - i}&1
\end{array}} \right)\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\
0
\end{array}} \right) = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1\\
{ - i}
\end{array}} \right)$

Where is the correct matrix of the operator $\sqrt {NOT} $ specified?

Comment: Somewhat related: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15381/square-root-of-pauli-operators-is-there-a-common-convention-to-define-them-uniq?rq=1

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Square root of Pauli operators: is there a common convention to define them uniquely?](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/15381/square-root-of-pauli-operators-is-there-a-common-convention-to-define-them-uniq). See also https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/3793/55

Comment: @glS You offer a more general question with a more general answer. My question is more specific, so I got more specific and simple answers.

Comment: well, the question as I see it here is "what is the correct definition of the square root of $\mathrm{NOT]\equiv X$?". The answer to which, as shown in the linked posts, is that there isn't a "correct" one; any matrix has multiple possible square roots

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They are the same up to a global phase.

Note that
$1 + i = \sqrt 2 e^{i\pi / 4}$.
That means
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{1 + i}&{1 - i}\\
{1 - i}&{1 + i}
\end{array}} \right) &= \frac{1}{2}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
\sqrt 2 e^{i\pi / 4}&\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi / 4}\\
\sqrt 2 e^{-i\pi / 4}&\sqrt 2 e^{i\pi / 4}
\end{array}} \right) \\
&= e^{i\pi / 4}.\frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1 &e^{-i\pi / 2}\\
e^{-i\pi / 2}&1
\end{array}} \right) \\
&= e^{i\pi / 4}.\frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
1 &-i\\
-i&1
\end{array}} \right).
\end{align*}

Comment: Thanks! But what do you mean by "global phase"?

Comment: You can find a good explanation for this phrase here: https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/5125/9474

Answer (score 9):

As mentioned already, both of those unitaries are the same up to a global phase. It might be useful to think about how you can actually arrive at one of these definitions in terms of the "Not gate" $X$.
Recall that because $X^2=I$ that you can express the exponential of $X$ using something very similar to Euler's formula:

\begin{align}
\exp\left(-i\theta X\right) = \cos\theta I  -i \sin\theta X 
\end{align}
So if we substitute $\theta = \frac{\pi}{2}$ we compute $\exp\left(-i\frac{\pi}{2} X\right)$ as

\begin{align}
X = i \exp\left(-i\frac{\pi}{2} X\right) &= \exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\exp\left(-i\frac{\pi}{2} X\right)
\end{align}

Note that the choice of a minus sign is actually important, since it describes which direction you rotate around the x-axis of the Bloch sphere to realize an $X$ gate which becomes relevant once you want to compute the square root of that operation. This suggests a possible definition
\begin{align}
\sqrt{X} &= \sqrt{\exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{2}\right)\exp\left(-i\frac{\pi}{2} X\right)} \\
&= \exp\left(i\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\exp\left(-i\frac{\pi}{4} X\right)\\
&= \frac{(1 + i)}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \cos\frac{\pi}{4}I -i \sin\frac{\pi}{4} X \right) \\
&=  \frac{(1 + i)}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1
\end{pmatrix} + 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & -i \\
-i & 0
\end{pmatrix} \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\begin{pmatrix}
1+i & 1-i \\
1-i & 1+i
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}

and so you can at least see how the first definition might have been derived, even if both gates are practically equivalent and therefore "correct".

Comment: This is a great addition to the first answer. It was interesting to see it. Thanks!